# Spring JSON Response: Serialize only the response object content (do not Wrap Root Value)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

In my application every restful service returns the following object, which indicate whether the request terminated with success or an error, it contains an optional error message and, of course, the object:

```
public class JSONResponse {

    public boolean success = true;
    public String errmsg = "";
    public Object body;

    /* getter/setter */
}
```

When I call the restful service, I get the following JSON:

```
{
   "JSONResponse":{
      "success":true,
      "errmsg":"",
      "body":[]
    }
 }
```

Unfortunately, I already have the client-side code which expects to get only the object content as this:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "errmsg":"",
   "body":[]
}
```

I would like to preserve my existing JS code. How can I configure the MappingJackson2JsonView to get a JSON with only the content of the "JSONResponse:" field.

The following is part of a simplified restful controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/list")
public JSONResponse list() {
    JSONResponse response = new JSONResponse();
    response.success(new String[] { "a", "b", "c"});
    return response;
}//EndMethod.
```

In the xml I use the *MappingJackson2JsonView* default view as in the partial attached xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="contentNegotiationManager"/>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Please list the Controller code that returns these objects. By default when returning an instance of a class like JSONResponse, there is no such wrapping. Additionally it looks a bit odd to me that you are signaling errors by adding some key to the returned document. In most cases this can be done better by using the correct return codes of the HTTP protocol (but it seems you don't want to change the client code, so please add some details about your controllers)

Comment: I actually use the error message to inform the client about semantic/logical errors, just an example when the user tries to save an object with a missing value, doing a check also on the server side. Is there a better way to do it? Which HTTP return code usually do you use for this kind of situations? Thanks for the comment and your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to remove the root key name from the generated JSON response, I updated the spring config file by adding `p:extractValueFromSingleKeyModel="true"`

```
<bean id="contentNegotiationManager"  class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">   
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true"/>
    <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />

    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
           <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
           <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
       </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="contentNegotiationManager"/>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"
                p:extractValueFromSingleKeyModel="true" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I also updated the root **beans** tag to provide "p" as in the following snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

#### A brief technical explanation

Doing some tests with the debugger, I noticed that the method [`writeValue`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValue(java.io.File,%20java.lang.Object)) of the `ObjectMapper` receives an HashMap with only one item, where the key is "JSONResponse" and the value is the object returned by the controller method. Therefore, the ObjectMapper will generate the JSON from this HashMap instance, hence the presence of "JSONResponse" as root, because the serializer starts from the hash map object.

By default the WRAP ROOT VALUE in spring has the value false, and does not affect the presence of "JSONResponse" string as root in the specific case. Indeed, by enabling it you will get `{ "HashMap": { "JSONResponse": ... }}`. Therefore, the `this.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false)` does not solve the issue.

The `MappingJackson2JsonView` has a method `setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel`, from the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/json/MappingJackson2JsonView.html#setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel-boolean-)  "*Set whether to serialize models containing a single attribute as a map or whether to extract the single value from the model and serialize it directly*". By default, it is false and does not extract the value from the hashmap, but the hashmap itself is the object converted to JSON. When this property is set to true, it extracts the value from the hash map and converts it in JSON.

Comment: JavaConfig: view.setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel(true);

Answer (score 0):

Define your own `ObjectMapper` like this:

```
public class MyCustomMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public MyCustomMapper() {
        //this.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);
        //this.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        this.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);
    }
}
```

Then add the bean definition in your xml:

```
<bean id="myCustomObjectMapper" class="put.your.package.name.MyCustomMapper"/>
```

Finally reconfigure the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="objectMapper" ref="myCustomObjectMapper" />
</bean>
```

Comment: MyCustomWrapper is correctly registered and its constructor is called, but when I call the rest service, the object root is still there. I also tried to call `this.disable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE)` within the constructor, but nothing. Do I need to write extra code to do it? Many thanks for your hints!