# RestController JSON Response object format

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs, jackson

I am using Spring Boot to return data from a Repository.  I would like to format my JSON so that it plays nicely with ExtJS' ajax handling.  Essentially I would like to include properties to handle success/failure, count, and errorMsg along with a List of data from the repository.

I have tried by creating a ResponseDTO object that I'm returning from my Rest Controller.

```
@RestController
public class AdminController {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(AdminController.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    private UserValidator userValidator;

    @GetMapping("/searchUsers")
    public ResponseDTO searchUsers(String name, String active) {
        int activeFlag;
        List<User> users;
        ResponseDTO resp;
        if(active.equals("true")) {
            activeFlag = 1;
        } else activeFlag=0;

        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            users= userService.findAllUsers(activeFlag);
        } else {
            users= userService.findByUsernameActive(name, activeFlag);
        }   

        return new ResponseDTO(users, true);
    }
}
```

Here's my DTO that I use in the controller:

```
public class ResponseDTO {
    private boolean success;
    private int count = 0;

    private List<?> values;

    public boolean getSuccess() {
        return this.success;
    }
    public void setState(boolean st) {
        this.success=st;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }
    public void setCount(int cnt) {
        this.count=cnt;
    }

    public List<?>getValues() {
        return this.values;
    }
    public void setValues(List<?> vals) {
        this.values = vals;
    }

    public ResponseDTO(List<?> items, boolean state) {
        this.success = state;
        values = items;
        this.count = items.size();
    }
}
```

Here's what the JSON I get back looks like:

```
{
  "ResponseDTO": {
                    "success":true,
                    "count":2,
                    "values":[{obj1 } , { obj2}]
                 }
}
```

what I would like to get is something more like:

```
{
   "success" : true,
   "count" : 2,
   "values" [{obj1},{obj2}]
}
```

I'm using Spring Boot and Jackson annotations.  I have used an annotation to ignore individual fields in the objects in the results array, but  I can't find a way to unwrap the ResponseDTO object to not include the class name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring JSON Response: Serialize only the response object content (do not Wrap Root Value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777358/spring-json-response-serialize-only-the-response-object-content-do-not-wrap-ro)

Comment: Do you want such a json for all POJOs or jus this one?

Comment: I want to unwrap just this POJO.

Comment: @pvlt - yes and no... I'm using Spring Boot so I'm not doing all the XML configuration of the app.

Comment: link what I present also contain answer with bean definition and ObjectMapper. maybe its ok for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you serialize ResponseDTO POJO, you should not get 'ResponseDTO' in the response by default. Because, the root wrap feature is disabled by default. See the doc [here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html). If you have the below code, please remove it.

```
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
```

Comment: I did this from my application.properties

spring.jackson.serialization.wrap-root-value=false